# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iloc'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As you can see in my program:
I tried to add a noise to my Data

```
from tkinter import messagebox, filedialog
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.svm import SVC

RSB_db = 10
Noised_Data = []

"""INPUT DATA
"""
Path_DataBase = filedialog.askopenfilename()
All_Data = pd.read_csv(Path_DataBase, header=None)
Shape = All_Data.shape
n_line = Shape[0]
n_column = Shape[1]
Data = All_Data.iloc[0:, :Shape[1] - 2]  # Extract Data



"""ADD Noise
"""
if RSB_db != 0:
    for i_line in range(n_line):
        print(i_line)
        White_noise_training = (max(Data.iloc[i_line, :]) * 10**(-RSB_db / 20)) * round(1, n_column)
        Noised_Data.iloc[i_line, :] = Data.iloc[i_line, :] + White_noise_training
```

then i got the error below :--------------------------

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/pedro.Grisard/Desktop/ocsvm/main.py", line 25, in <module>
    Noised_Data.iloc[i_line] = Data.iloc[i_line, :] + White_noise_training
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iloc' ```
````

Comment: Please post the full stack trace, we can't see which line is causing the error.

Comment: @joao I posted the full stack trace as you demand

Comment: @BoarGules  in this line ```Data = All_Data.iloc[0:, :Shape[1] - 2]``` i tried only to remove the last 2 columns from my data because i dont want to add noise there.

Comment: @BoarGules then i generated noise using this line ```White_noise_training = (max(Data.iloc[i_line, :]) * 10**(-RSB_db / 20)) * round(1, n_column) ``` 
After that i want to add noise to my new data called  ```Noised_Data```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store the modified data in another dataframe `Noised_Data`, you can use:

```
RSB_db = 10
##Noised_Data = []                                        # <===  remove this line

"""INPUT DATA
"""
Path_DataBase = filedialog.askopenfilename()
All_Data = pd.read_csv(Path_DataBase, header=None)
Shape = All_Data.shape
n_line = Shape[0]
n_column = Shape[1]
Data = All_Data.iloc[0:, :Shape[1] - 2]  # Extract Data
Noised_Data = Data.copy()                                 # <=== Add this line


"""ADD Noise
"""
if RSB_db != 0:
    for i_line in range(n_line):
        print(i_line)
        White_noise_training = (max(Data.iloc[i_line, :]) * 10**(-RSB_db / 20)) * round(1, n_column)
        Noised_Data.iloc[i_line, :] = Data.iloc[i_line, :] + White_noise_training
```

In your original code `Noised_Data` is defined as an empty list and is not a dataframe.  Hence, it has no attribute `iloc` which is for dataframe.  If you want to store the modified data in another dataframe, you can copy it before the processing, like the modified codes above.

Comment: No I dont Want to modify my ```Data``` because i will use it later.
i try your solution it work but i need to keep my ```Data```.
So How I can do ?

Comment: @jd10031994  In that case, you can copy `Data` first.  Let me write it in solution.

Comment: @jd10031994   See my edit above.  Defined `Noised_Data` as a copy of `Data`.